# React-native basic project gives error: _JS call: _fbBatchedBridge is undefined

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, redux

I am currently trying to run a redux/react-native project. Currently I just have a basic application with one screen that should display the text "test" but I get this weird error on ios that is

```
"Unable to execute JS call: _fbBatchedBridge is undefined"
```

I then tried to install the application on android through react-native run-android and it says that the developer server isn't up. I checked localhost:8081/status and it does show that the developer server is running.

**What I have tried**

I have tried a bunch of different things. It’s definitely not the developer server. I tried commenting out 4 lines of code in the file in /node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh which were lines 17-20.

```
  #if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" = "iphonesimulator" ]]; then
    #  echo "Skipping bundling for Simulator platform"
    #  exit 0;
    #fi
```

This was causing a bunch of people that same issue. Unfortunately that didn’t fix my problem so I kept reading and from what I read it could be that the native aspect of the application isn’t able to read and interpret the javascript. Any help would be much appreciated.

My index.ios.js file (entry) looks like this:

```
import React from 'react-native';

var React = require('react-native');

const {
  AppRegistry
} = React;

import App from './app/containers/app';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('InstallApp', () => App);
```

Comment: Might not fix your problem, but you're importing react-native with both a require and the new import syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when the connection is not made between react-native and android device automatically , for explicitly making the connection you can run

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

provided you have not modified port in any of the system files for rn.

Comment: I have tried this an unfortunately I have had no luck :(